# 2d dynamic array program crashes

Tags: c++, c, arrays, malloc

I wrote a dynamically allocated 2D array and for some reason it's not working as I intend it to.
I allocated for a 14x5 array to store values in.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   int i, j, count, count2;
   int size, keysize, column;

   size = 7;  keysize = 10; column = 5;
   int row = (size * keysize) / column;  // 14

   char **arr = (char **)malloc(column * sizeof(char *));
   for(i=0; i<row; i++)
      arr[i] = (char *)malloc(row * sizeof(char *));

   count=0;
   count2=0;

   for(i=0; i<keysize; i++)
   {
      for(j=0; j<size; j++)
      {
         printf("arr[%d][%d]=", count2, count);
         arr[count2][count] = 'C';
         printf("%c\n", arr[count2][count]);
         count++;

         if(count == 5)
         { 
            count = 0;
            count2++;
         }
      }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

It seems that the program crashes when a value is to be inserted at the location arr[6][0].
Before that it works fine.
I inserted some printf statements to capture this occurring.

I am not sure why it's doing this, the allocation of memory looks fine with me but I am no expert.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: note : please avoid casting the return of `malloc()`

Comment: `arr[i] = (char *)malloc(row * sizeof(char *));`. You should allocate `(rows * elementsize)` but it's not immediately clear how many rows or what size each element.

Comment: `column = 5; malloc(column * sizeof(char *));` This makes space for 5 pointers to rows and then you call `arr[6][0]` so this will access past the end of the array.

Comment: @SouravGhosh he has both the C and C++ tags and if he wants it to compile with a C++ compiler, he needs to cast it, C++ doesn't do arbitrary pointer type conversions implicitly. (I know it's not advisable but some people just write programs that compile on both C++ and C compilers)

Comment: @PeterT `#include <stdio.h>` and `malloc()` are not for `C++`. Also, tagging both `C` and `c++` is mostly considered as tag spamming.

Answer (score 0):

change to

```
char **arr = (char **)malloc(row * sizeof(char *));
for(i=0; i<row; i++)
   arr[i] = (char *)malloc(column * sizeof(char));
```

Answer (score 0):

I notice the question marked with the c++ tag, the clear way to do this in c++ is to use `std::vector`. So I'm answering this as if it were a C question:

It looks like you haven't allocated enough space here.

```
column = 5;
char **arr = (char **)malloc(column * sizeof(char *));
```

This makes space for 5 pointers to rows. Then later on when you are looping:

```
for(i=0; i<keysize; i++)//note keysize is 10
{
    for(j=0; j<size; j++){ // note size is 7
        arr[count2][count];
        count++;
        if(count == 5){
            count = 0;
            count2++;//gets incremented every time the inner loop runs
        }
    }
}
```

Because `count2` gets incremented every time the inner loop runs it will get as big as `keysize` eventually. That means that `arr[keysize][0]` must be valid, which it isn't because you in effect made `arr[5][14]`. The first failure is when you call arr[6][0] which accesses past the end of the array and causes your program to crash.

If the intent here is to initialize variables then to fix this you probably want to loop over the same values for dimensions that you used for allocating the memory.